# LINQ: Find a list of strings in a list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I am writing a LINQ query where i want to check if the file name contains one of the following values: ".xls", "xlsx", ".csv"

```
var results = api.GetAttachments(id).Where(x => 
                  x.fileName.Contains(".xls") ||
                  x.fileName.Contains(".xlsx") || 
                  x.fileName.Contains(".csv"))
              .ToList();
```

I would like to reduce repetition in this linq query and make the file types a variable. So I wrote a list of string variable

```
List<string> fileTypes = new List<string>(new string[] {".xls", ".xlsx", ".csv" });
```

How can i incorporate this list of strings in the first query? Basically I want to select objects if the file name is one of the strings mentioned above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you consider calling your linq query inside a foreach loop for `fileTypes` ?

Comment: 1.  What happens if you send a filename with Cap Extension .XLS?
2.   What happens if the file name is `myFile.csv.txt` 

dont use contains use path get extension and a case insensitive equals